# Blazor WASM .net HttpClient with MultipartFormDataContent not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, multipartform-data, blazor-webassembly

i have problem with HttpClient in Blazor WASM with CI3 backend

```
// __http is HttpClient injected form DI
var form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
form.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("multipart/form-data");
form.Add(new StringContent("thisistoken"), "token");

var res = await _http.PostAsync("someuri", form);

Console.WriteLine(await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

and it returns

```
{"sts":false,"message":"Kesalahan","token":"","data":"Unauthorized"}
```

my backend doesn't read token variable that send by HttpClient using MultipartFormDataContent

but when i used **Javascript** (JQUERY AJAX), **postman** and **curl** it works!! but HttpClient don't

here my curl command

```
curl -X POST  https://someuri  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data;' -F token=thisistoken
```

and it gets

```
{"sts":false,"message":"Kesalahan","token":"thisistoken","data":"Unauthorized"}
```

here my backend code

```
public function simpan(){

        // load member model
        $this->load->model("Member_model",'member');

        $token = htmlentities($this->input->post('token'));
        $return = [];
        $token_status = $this->tokenStatusMobile($token, 'SEND_DATA');

        // Token does not match
        if(! $token_status['sts']){
            echo json_encode([
                'sts' => false,
                'message' => 'Kesalahan',
                'token' => $token,
                'data' => 'Unauthorized'
            ]);
            return;
        }

....
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

ok i just remove this line

```
form.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("multipart/form-data");
```

and everything working fine

Comment: 2 years later, yeah this one helped. :)